# Why Resident Memory is Increasing in my Java Application?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, memory, primefaces

I have an application deployed in Glassfish 4.0 Application Server. Such an application has an intensive access, that is, there is a lot of users periodically making accesses to a web service (aprox 200 users accessing the server each 20 seconds). I am using 512 mb of permgen and 1024mb of heap size. My Server is a CentOS virtual server, with three cores of 1.8Ghz and 2Gb of memory.

My JVM is
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

I already tried to find the memory leak using VisualVM and JConsole. But the Garbage Collector seems to work fine on these tools, because the heap and permgen memories increase and decrease periodically. However, the RES (resident) memory only increases, as I can see using top command.

Regarding my application, it uses MySQL, JPA 2, EclipseLink implementation of JPA and JSF 2 and Primefaces (5.2).

So why my resident memory increase?

Comment: Well, you are the only one thst can see what is in there… and what jvm are you running?

Comment: And did you search  google to find possible causes? A quick search resulted in some interesting things to investigate

Comment: I forgot to mention that my JVM is 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Your code is most likely leaking memory (i.e it keeps referencing unused objects somewhere). A profiler can point out which objects it are. Just check which objects accumulate with time and never decrease. This question can't be reasonably answered without data from a profiler (even then, once you got hand of it, you'd usually already have answered it by yourself; this kind of questions always end up unanswered or answered by OP itself only).

Comment: I already used a profiler (JConsole and VisualVM), but they didn't show us an object that increases over time. Actually, we have been monitoring the memory using a profiler, and we can see the memory usage increasing and decreasing, which is normal. On the other hand, the resident memory increases slowly.